# Spring valued by Interface in javax.validation.Constraint

Tags: java, spring, constraints

I wrote a custom annotation using javax. The problem is I need to put annotation in one module(annotations) and validator in the another module(validators). But only module with validators can see the module with annotations.

So I can't put my validator inside "validatedBy":

**//It works only if MyAnnotation and MyValidator exist in the same module**

```
`@Constraint(validatedBy = {MyValidator.class}) 
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {   
//
}`
```

I tried create an interface in the same module as an annotation and write my validator as an implementation in my module with validators and create a bean:

**//module with annotations**

```
`*@Constraint(validatedBy = {MyValidatorInterface.class}) 
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {   
//
}`
public interface MyValidatorInterface extends ConstraintValidator<MyAnnotation, Object> {
}*
```

**//module with validators**

```
`*@AutoService(ConstraintValidator.class)
public class MyValidatorImpl implements MyValidatorInterface {
//
}`
```

```
`@Configuration
public class ValidationConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyValidatorInterface getMyValidatorInterface() {
        return new MyValidatorImpl();
    }
}*`
```

**When I try to use my Class with MyAnnotation I get an exception:**

"org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'some_path.MyValidatorInterface': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [some_path.MyValidatorInterface]: Specified class is an interface"

Is it possible to find a solution and keep annotation and validator in different modules?